# JHipster - Improve error messages on frontend

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

When I want to delete an entity that is linked to other entities in JHipster, the modal shows the expected error:

```
error.internalServerError
```

However, it would be nice if JHipster could show a nice error message that explains there is other data linked and you should delete that first.

Does JHipster provide tools for returning meaningful errors like this?

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways to go to achieve this, which depends on the error itself.

If the error is thrown by your self, use the `CustomParameterizedException` class. This gets automatically passed to the angular error resolver, so you will get a nice message, you defined.

If the error occurs somewhere inside spring, and you want to get a clearer message, I personally prefer to change the `ExceptionTranslator` class, and change the plain "internalServerError" to `e.getMessage()`.

You may limit this to dev profile for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

in the class [ExceptionTranslator](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/web/rest/errors/ExceptionTranslator.java) are some common errors handled. When you are deleting a resource which is referred over a foreign key in some children, then a ***org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException*** is thrown. This exception is handled in the method ***processRuntimeException***.

In order to create other message you can use create a

```
@ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorVM> processDataIntegrityViolationException(DataIntegrityViolationException ex){
}
```

The question is: what will be the message that you want to add? IMHO I think that you should catch the exception at the place where the call was done and then you can create a proper message that can be sent to the user.